# open() function in Linux with extended characters (128-255) returns -1 error

Tags: c++, c, linux

When i try to create a file in LINUX using open() function, i get an error **'-1'** for the filename that contains extended character (ex: Björk.txt). Here the file contains a special character **ö** (ASCII 148)

I am using the below code:

`char* szUnixPath`

> /home/user188/Output/Björk.txt

```
open(szUnixPath, locStyle, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
```

I always get a -1 error, and NO FILE is created.

As the OS encounters the ASCII 148, it throws an error.

The same function works perfectly fine if i use a tilde ~ (ASCII 126, example: Bj~rk.txt) or any other character below ASCII value 128.

can somebody explain why do i get the -1 error only for filename having special character ranging between 128-255 ?

Comment: Not sure, but you might need to use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I tried UTF-8 encoding. didn't work ! Well, i use CP437

Comment: How do you input the name of the file? Input from the console or a GUI? Hardcoded in the source? Are you sure the encoding of the filename you pass to `open` is the same as the encoding used by the filesystem for its filenames?

Comment: Try comparing the behavior of `char bjork1[] = "Bj\366rk"` and `char bjork2[] = "Bj\303\266rk"`.

Comment: "*character ö (ASCII 148)*" <- ö doesn't have an ASCII code. As for the question, on Linux, filenames are just byte sequences, so you need to use the same encoding that was used creating the file. If `ls` shows the name correctly, this is the encoding of your current locale, just type `locale` to find out.

Comment: This definitely should work just fine on linux. What is the actual code you have?

Comment: You are surely making an incorrect association between failure of `fopen()` and characters with value greater than 127 generally.  There is no inherent incompatibility there, but you do need to encode all characters of the filename in the same way that they are encoded by the OS in directory entries.

Comment: @adan as said it seems strange you probably have a locale error you can try this code on your machine and see if you get an error with no local set
https://wandbox.org/permlink/aPKLDoTp4VYvHhLk

Comment: I can see the locale as below:                                                         LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: What type of filesystem are you using?

Comment: @adam well, then the UTF-8 encoding of `ö` (2 bytes!) would work. To be absolutely sure, try [or523's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46849937/2371524).

Comment: @SteveSummit char bjork2[] = "Bj\303\266rk" is what i need. My code gives me "Bj\366rk" which is wrong. What have i missed?

Comment: @Pierrot This is what i get as the output:                                               opening Björk.txt with locale en_US.UTF-8
opening Björk.txt with locale en_US.UTF8, I don't get an error

Comment: @adam Is the "wrong" version of the string coming from user-typed input, or something?  If so, I guess you'll have to figure out how to set the locale of the input system to UTF-8. (But, yes, I see from the environment variables you posted that the locale seems to be UTF-8 already.  But there may be other settings having to do with your keyboard or terminal window or something.)

Comment: My program extracts the file with special character from inside of a zip file and reads its characters. Then finally creates a new file with the same name

Answer (score 1):

I recommend just trying yourself to see what bytes this name contains.

Create the file in a directory, then run the following simple C program:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* Open directory */
    DIR * currdir = opendir(".");

    /* Iterate over files */
    struct dirent * directory_entry = NULL;
    while (NULL != (directory_entry = readdir(currdir)))
    {
        char * entry_name = directory_entry->d_name;
        printf("Directory entry: %s\n", entry_name);
        printf("Name bytes (len: %d):\n", strlen(entry_name));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(entry_name); ++i)
        {
            printf("\tname[%d] = %d\n", i, entry_name[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

We can easily see in the output that 'Björk' length is 6-bytes. And we can see these bytes values:

```
Directory entry: Björk
Name bytes (len: 6):
    name[0] = 66
    name[1] = 106
    name[2] = -61
    name[3] = -74
    name[4] = 114
    name[5] = 107
```

Comment: You are right. I get the same output but i am just curious to know that how the special character ö value are negative -61 and -74

Comment: @adam: That is the UTF-8 encoding of ö, incorrectly printed as signed values. (The normal presentation would be hexadecimal C3 B6, which is the 2s complement representation of the integers shown in this answer.)

Comment: In my code i am getting the output as 'Bj\224rk.txt' while using the output charset UTF8. can somebody tell where am i going wrong? I have already set the character encoding to UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Filenames in Linux are generally specified in UTF-8, not CP437. The `open` is failing because the filename you're passing doesn't match the one in the OS.

Try opening this file instead:  `/home/user188/Output/Bj\xc3\xb6rk.txt`. This is the special character encoded in UTF-8 as two bytes.

Comment: "*are generally specified in UTF-8*" <- not really, although common... they are generally just opaque byte sequences, using whatever encoding was used creating them.

Comment: @felix: that depends on the filesystem, no?

Comment: @rici some filesystems have options for converting filename encodings, but that's not generally the case. The userspace API just treats the names as byte sequences.

Comment: @felix filesystem samba, with unix encoding set to utf-8. Attempt to use a filename string which is invalid utf-8. Result?

Comment: @rici yes, smbfs/cifs is one of those that do translations. The result should be a simple `ENOENT`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen but if you use `ls` what encoding is used to display the filename? The filename needs an encoding even if the filesystem doesn't care, and in Linux the encoding is extremely likely to be UTF-8.

Comment: @MarkRansom `ls` (probably, I didn't check the code) doesn't care and just "shovels bytes" to `stdout`. Yes, nowadays very likely to find UTF-8, but there's no guarantee and Linux supports a lot of other encodings as well. If you switch between encodings and create files, you end up with a horrible mess of differently encoded file names -- such things happened to Linux users ;)

Comment: @felix: that's why i said it depends on the *filesystem*, because it is the filesystem which interprets (and possibly rejects) the filename string. And I don't believe samba/cifs is uncommon, although I no longer use it.

Comment: @rici it's a special case because it interfaces with a windows server and on windows, filenames **do** have encoding information. A typical Linux filesystem will just not care. Btw, if configured correctly (the "unix encoding" set to the same encoding your locale is using), what smbfs does is completely transparent to the caller.

Comment: @felix: Exactly the same thing would happen if you use a mounted NTFS partition on your local machine (which is something which does apply to one of the machines I use). Some Linux filesystems don't care; others do. *It depends on the filesystem.* (And SMBFS will not handle an invalid UTF-8 encoding, regardless of your locale settings. It is just less likely to happen.)

Comment: @rici SMBFS will handle whatever encoding you configure, which is necessary because the windows server DOES use encodings in filenames. NTFS is another exception for a similar reason: it's a windows filesystem. Genuine Unix filesystems don't do such things.