# how to convert text from CP437 encoding to UTF8 encoding?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

In Windows, the value of the Unicode character `ö` (Latin small letter o with diaeresis) in the CP437 character set is `148`.

In Linux, the byte value for `ö` in the UTF-8 encoding is:

```
-61(Hi Byte) 
-74(Lo Byte)
(unsigned value = 46787)
```

My Question is, how can I convert from `148` from CP437 to UTF-8 in C++ on Linux?

The detailed info for my problem lies here:

[open() function in Linux with extended characters (128-255) returns -1 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849332/)

Temporary solution:
[C++11 supports the conversion to UTF-8  using `codecvt_utf8`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA8S7.png)

Comment: The `CP437` character set of `ö` is 148, which has nothing to do with Unicode.  The unicode value for `ö` is 246, which has nothing to do with CP437. Linux has nothing to do with any of this. UTF8 is an encoding, not a locale.

Comment: The question is: "how to convert text from CP437 encoding to UTF8 encoding?"

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks. Any suggesstions on how to do this?

Comment: Interpreting UTF-8 as little-endian 16-bit integers is also not a thing anyone should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, you can use the Win32 [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx) function to convert data from CP437 to UTF-16, and then use the [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) function to convert data from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

On Linux, you can use a Unicode conversion library, like [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) (which are available for Windows, too).

---

In C++11 and later, you can use [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) to:

- convert from CP437 to either UTF-16 or UTF-32/UCS-4 (if you can get/make a `codecvt` for CP437, that is).
- then, convert from UTF-16 or UTF-32/UCS-4 to UTF-8.

You can't use [`codecvt_utf8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) to convert from CP437 to UTF-8 directly.  It only supports conversions between:

- UTF-8 and UCS-2 (not UTF-16!)
- UTF-8 and UTF-32/UCS-4.

You have to use [`codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) for conversions between UTF-8 and UTF-16.

Or, you can use [`mbrtoc16()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrtoc16) to convert CP437 to UTF-16 using a CP437 locale, and then use [`c16rtomb()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/c16rtomb) to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 using a UTF-8 locale (if your STL library implements a fix for [DR488](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2059.htm#dr_488), otherwise `c16rtomb()` only supports UCS-2 and not UTF-16!).

---

Otherwise, just create your own CP437-to-UTF8 lookup table for the 256 possible CP437 bytes, and then do the conversion manually, one byte at a time.

Comment: That's actually a good information. Could you please help sharing more information about the usage these conversion library which could be helpful

Comment: Read their respective documentations and examples

Comment: @adam if you want to roll your own the [Wikipedia page for CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) contains the code points for all 256 characters. Encoding those into UTF-8 is easy, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/148766/5987 for just one example.

Comment: Here's a better link for the conversion table: ftp://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP437.TXT

Answer (score 2):

It is not in C++, but you can also use bash to convert a file:

```
$ iconv -f CP437 -t UTF-8 input_file_name.txt -o output_file_name.txt
```

Comment: Note that this does not correctly translate control characters.

Answer (score 0):

I did a working code from @remy-lebeau response. I hope it helps.

```cpp
std::string cp2UTF8(int codePage, const char* in, int inlen) {
    // first convert input from codePage to wide char
    int widelen = MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, in, inlen, 0, 0);
    std::wstring wide(widelen, L'\0');
    MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, in, inlen, &wide[0], widelen);
    // then convert wide char to utf8
    int utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wide.data(), widelen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string utf8(utf8len, '\0');
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wide.data(), widelen, &utf8[0], utf8len, NULL, NULL);
    return utf8;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution to Convert CP437 to UTF8. This works perfectly in LINUX

```
        BYTE high, low;
        WORD result;
        if (sCMResult.wChar > 0x80 && sCMResult.wChar <= 0x7ff)
        {
            low = (0xc0 | ((sCMResult.wChar >> 6) & 0x1f));
            high = (0x80 | (sCMResult.wChar & 0x3f));
            result = low | (high << 8);
        }
```

Full post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148766/5987)

Comment: No, this is only half of the solution. You still need something to convert the bytes of CP437 to Unicode codepoints. If you don't you'll get valid UTF-8 output, but it will be the wrong characters.